# How can i add new relationship to a model after install a new package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a modular system with Laravel packages. I have many packages such as user, profile, post and etc.

I want to add a new relationship to my models in the application or in my packages.

For example :

I have a model called User, and I create new package called Profile.
I want after install the Profile package, add a new relationship to the User model. but I don't want to add a Profile trait manually to my user model because I want to create a modular system and I don't want my User package to depend on my Profile package.

what is your solution?

**Answer**

***Eventually I found a solution.***

dynamic relation.

[Laravel - Eloquent - Dynamically defined relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448066/laravel-eloquent-dynamically-defined-relationship)

Comment: Eventually I found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

With your models, you simply add the relationship. Example in your user model you would add a new method

```
public function profile(){

  return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

In your profile model, you will want to add a user function.

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class)
}
```

But then you will need to add the new migration so that you have a profile linked to your user, so you would do something like this:

```
php artisan make:migration add_profile_to_users_table --table=users
```

Then in the new migration, add this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('profile_id);
        $table->foreign('profile_id')->references('id')->on('profile');

    });
}
```

Comment: In this solution if i remove my Profile package i have error in my user model. i want inject profile relation to my user Model from Profile package.

Comment: You are saying profile package.. So, what package are you using? If you are creating your own profile model, etc, then the solution above is what you will need to do. If you are using a 3rd-party package, tell me what package you are using.

Comment: I have create my own packages. but in your solution . if i remove profile package. i have error in User model . i dont want User model or User package to depend on profile package. i want if i removed profile package User model worked correct.

Comment: ok.. I think I understand you issue then.  So, a couple of ways you could do it...
First, with your new migration, you can add nullable. $table->unsignedBigInteger('profile_id)->nullable(); That is simplest way, but IMO, not real clean. This would be cleaner. So, in your new migration, you will have a down function..
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table){
    Schema::dropColumn('profile_id');
}
}
If you use that approach, if you remove your profile package, then you would need to run the down method for the new migration.

Comment: Okay. migration is not my main issue. actually my problem is classes. please attention to me. if I remove Profile package, then we had a used class of Profile that not exist. i want inject one to many profile relation to User model with Profile package service provider or something like that.  when I removed my Profile package then HasOne relation is removed without edit my User Model.

Comment: Good luck with that. If you have a user model that depends on a profile package and you remove your profile package, then obviously you will have to modify your user model.