# Laravel eloquent how to dynamically create relations?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to dynamically create different relationships (oneToOne, manyToMany, oneToMany) for my model with different tables and foreign keys and then retrieve my model with all this relations. Is there any way to do so? For example, instead of doing something like this:

```php
public function relOne()
{
    return $this->hasMany('one', 'foreign_one', 'one');
}
        
public function relTwo()
{
    return $this->hasMany('two', 'foreign_two', 'two');
}
```

I need to do something like this:

```php
$model->createRelation('relOne', function ($model) {
    return $model->hasMany('one', 'foreign_one', 'one');
});

$model->createRelation('relTwo', function ($model) {
     return $model->hasMany('two', 'foreign_two', 'two');
});
```

P.S. I have Laravel 6.X

Comment: Welcome to SO ... have you seen this? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#dynamic-relationships  ... or are you trying to do this only for a single instance?

Comment: @lagbox Thanks for your reply! These must be specific to a single instance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Eloquent - Dynamically defined relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448066/laravel-eloquent-dynamically-defined-relationship)

Answer (score 1):

i recommend using 
[eloquent-dynamic-relation](https://github.com/i-rocky/eloquent-dynamic-relation)

you can install it:

```
composer require i-rocky/eloquent-dynamic-relation
```

in your model use the trait:

```
    use Rocky\Eloquent\HasDynamicRelation;

class MyModel extends Model {
  use HasDynamicRelation;
}
```

then you can simply write:

```
MyModel::addDynamicRelation('some_relation', function (MyModel $myModel) {
    return $myModel->hasMany(SomeRelatedModel::class);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately , my model is fully dynamic, so it didn't even have preset table(I create instance and set table in instance across with all fields etc. using fabric), so this trait doesn't work for me, because it can't find table and throws error.