# eloquent relations with extend user model sentinel laravel package

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, cartalyst-sentinel

I have a class User that extends

```
<?php

namespace App;

class User extends \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser
{
    public function chalets(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Chalet');
    }
}
```

and i have Chalet Class

```
class Chalet extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description',
    ];
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

And i have method to add chalet by user :

```
public function postCreateChalet(Request $request){
        $chalet = new Chalet([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'description' => $request->input('description')
        ]);
        Sentinel::getUserRepository()->setModel('App\User');
        $user = Sentinel::getUser();
        $user->chalets()->save($chalet);
        return ('chalet has created');
    }
```

and its give me an error :

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser::chalets()
```

Is it a right way to extend User class ?

I have searched for ways to extend the User class. I found this question:[Model Inheritance in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973850/model-inheritance-in-laravel) didn't help me though.

I'm using Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you're getting indicates Sentinel is still referring to the default stock Sentinel's **EloquentUser** model. Make sure you point to **your** extended user model with the published Sentinel configurations.

1. Run the below command

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider"
   ```
2. Open up the published config file at 'config\cartalyst.sentinel.php'
3. Modify it from the below content:

   `'users' => [
       'model' => 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser',
   ],`

   to:

   `'users' => [
       'model' => 'App\User',
   ],`

For more information, refer to https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/wiki/Extending-Sentinel

You won't need the following line after you configured it via config:

```
Sentinel::getUserRepository()->setModel('App\User');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for me I needed to add the trait:

```
use Authenticatable;
```

to the User class (as above) being used by Sentinel.